# Socket.io-Stream não emite eventos

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Tenho uma aplicação cliente que envia arquivos através de socket para meu servidor, esses arquivos chegam como stream através do Socket.io-stream, e eu os escrevo no disco sem nenhum problema tudo ia bem, até eu ter que executar um tratamento em cada arquivo após sua escrita, ao tentar detectar os eventos percebi que não havia nenhum deles, alguém tem ideia do que pode estar acontecendo ?

```
const fileStream = fs.createWriteStream(filename);

  socketStream.pipe(fileStream);

  fileStream.on('close', ()=>{
     console.log('close.');
  });

  fileStream.on('finish', ()=>{
    console.log('Finalizado.');
  });
```